# Why i can't edit mat-button padding?

Tags: css, angular, sass, material-ui, angular-material

default padding of mat-button's,  i need to subscribe the default padding (16px)

I've been trying to set the padding of a mat-button, but the component's style isn't changing. What can I do, I've already tried changing CSS properties, but none of them solve the proble

```
 COMPONENT.HTML
    <header>
  <mat-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <div class="example-sidenav-content">
      <button type="button" mat-flat-button (click)="toogleDrawer()" class="menu-button">
        <mat-icon class="menu-icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <img src="../../../assets/imagens/Logotipo-header.png" alt="LOGOTIPO EUROTEXTIL" class="toolbar-logo">
    <span class="toolbar-usu">{{  profile.name  }}</span>
  </mat-toolbar>
</header>
```

and the SCSS

```
header {
  padding: 0 3%;
  height: 12vh;
  background: $primary-color;
  border: solid 2px greenyellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  .toolbar {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: $primary-color;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

    .menu-button {
      color: $white;
      background-color: rgb(86, 9, 230);
      padding: !15px;
    }

    .menu-icon {
      background-color: yellowgreen;
      margin:0 auto ;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code of what you already tried?

Comment: <button type="button" mat-flat-button (click)="toogleDrawer()" class="menu-button">
        <mat-icon class="menu-icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

Componente.html
_______________________________

    .menu-button {
      color: $white;
      background-color: rgb(86, 9, 230);
      padding: 2px;
    }

style.scss

Comment: Please provide it in the question using the code tags

Comment: done!, sorry i'm begginer here

Comment: @JoãoVictorFrassi, please use `assets/imagens/Logotipo-header.png`, **NOT** `../../../assets...`. Angular copy your assets folder in the same place it create the index.html, so, from this "index.html" the images should be looking for from this route. Think that when you build an app, it's doesn't matter the structure of our application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Eliseo was very helpful in solving my problem, but in truth, the issue wasn't the padding. I found that the problem was with the min-width property. The mat-button comes with a default min-width set to 64px.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with exact `mat-button` but work with similar 3rd party libraries and can provide usuall steps to override such styles:

1. pass styles or style classes to the componen if it accept ones or use inline styles.
2. global classes with higher precision (scope to your angular component if it necessary only there)
3. global styles with `!important`
4. ::ng-deep.

Last one is better not to use at all. The 3rd one should be used only for styles which are already provided as inline by the 3rd party library.

Comment: Please, avoid use `!important`, makes more specific css

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method if you are changing padding only for buttons in that specific component is to add a `class` and style it in that component's css or sass file.

If you are doing it globally for all `mat-button`s use `.mat-button { padding: 10px !important; }` in your styles.sass

With your edited question `.menu-button {padding :15px}` should do the work

Comment: Please, avoid use `!important`, makes more specific css

Comment: Yes you are right @Eliseo but material components come with built-in styles, in order to override it, we need to either add important to its default class name or add a class name to the button and edit it in the specific components css

Comment: About [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).If you add `!important` in any .css, you're forcing this value. It's a bad idea. You early can want to change, and makes more dificult change

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what you are trying to reach, here the user **is** trying to force the css, you can either create a class and add styles there `which you and I explained in our answers` or use !important to force it if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first problem is in css section.
You didn't close the herder after styling it with **braces**( } ).
And the same problem occurred exactly after styling your toolbar.
As I understood from your question, your **`menu-icon`** class doesn't get padding: 16px?
If so, you can write in front of it:
`padding: 16px! important`.

> This helps you by prioritizing the application of this padding in the
> execution of the style.

Comment: Please, avoid use `!important`, makes more specific css

Comment: this organization is a particularity of SCSS languagem

Answer (score 0):

Please, to all the response: try avoid use `!important`. You need "more especific" css.

First we need find (using developer's tools of navigator F12) our button and see what it's the property that make the padding.

In the case of a button you see some like, e.g. for a mat-raised-button

```
<button _ngcontent-ng-c626419816="" 
        mat-raised-button="" color="primary" 
        class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mat-mdc-raised-button mat-primary
               mat-mdc-button-base" 
        mat-ripple-loader-class-name="mat-mdc-button-ripple" ng-reflect-color="primary">
       <span class="mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple mdc-button__ripple"></span>
       <span class="mdc-button__label">Primary</span>
       <span class="mat-mdc-focus-indicator"></span>
       <span class="mat-mdc-button-touch-target"></span>
       <span class="mat-ripple mat-mdc-button-ripple"></span>
</button>
```

See the "class": `mdc-button mdc-button--raised mat-mdc-raised-button mat-primary mat-mdc-button-base`

What class indicate the "padding"? You can see that is the class `mat-mdc-raised-button`

```
.mat-mdc-raised-button {
    font-family: var(--mdc-protected-button-label-text-font);
    font-size: var(--mdc-protected-button-label-text-size);
    letter-spacing: var(--mdc-protected-button-label-text-tracking);
    font-weight: var(--mdc-protected-button-label-text-weight);
    text-transform: var(--mdc-protected-button-label-text-transform);
    height: var(--mdc-protected-button-container-height);
    border-radius: var(--mdc-protected-button-container-shape);
    padding: 0 var(--mat-protected-button-horizontal-padding, 16px);
    box-shadow: var(--mdc-protected-button-container-elevation-shadow);
}
```

So we need makes more specific this class, so we add one class to the button

```
<button class="large-button" mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
```

And now, in **global styles** (can be the styles.scss or what ever we include in angular.json) we can use

```
.large-button.mat-mdc-raised-button {
  padding: 32px
}
```

That's all the mat-raised-button with class "large-button" will be a padding of "32px"

If we have a serie of buttons inside a div with a class we can also

```
    <div class="custom-nav-bar">
        <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
        <button mat-raised-button disabled>Disabled</button>
    </div>

//For more especific:

.custom-nav-bar .mat-mdc-raised-button {
  padding: 32px
}
```

See that, as the class `mat-mdc-raised-button` is the class that have the button we "concatenate" the class: class-button`.`our-custom-class. Some times the property we can change is through some like `.class-ppal .another-class` and we need use `.class-ppal.our-custom-class .another-class`

NOTE: If we want change **all the buttons**m the tecnica is different, you change the css variable in themes

more [about Specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo, your comment was very enriching to my process!!